# Append product names in single list in Scrapy

Tags: python, list, append, scrapy

My current scrapy spider pulls product titles from a website as desired, but places each start_url's extractions in a seperate `['product']` list. I would like all start_url extractions to be placed into a single list (for each respective class type: product, price, etc) so I could then call each product title from the list in future manipulation of the extractions.

Here is my current spider:

```
 from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
 from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
 from proj.items import projItem

 class siteSpider(BaseSpider):
     name = "newSpider"
     allowed_domains = ["http://www.sample.url/"]
     start_urls = [
         "http://sample1.url",
         "http://sample2.url"
             ]

     def parse(self, response):
         hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
         items = []
         item = FlecheNoireItem()
         item ["product"] = hxs.select('//h2/a[contains(@class,"next_prev")]/text()').extract()
         items.append(item)
         return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to do your manipulations? If you want a general list that can be used all throughout your spider you could use:

```
class siteSpider(BaseSpider):
    ...
    generic_dict = {'product': [], 'price': [], 'etc': []}
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        self.generic_dict['product'].append(hxs.select(...))
        ...

    def manipulations(self):
        ...manipulations here...
        return self.generic_dict
```

The reason you had all these different lists is because for each `start_urls` url, scrapy calls a new `parse` function. It therefore reinitializes your `items` list each time.